# Migrating a server from Apache to Nginx - how is my request handled?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, nginx, php

I'm trying to migrate a service from a server to another.

It's a simple `php` app.

On the first server (`Apache`) I could request a `JSON` in the following way:

```
my.vhost.myDomain.tld/apps?query=toto&params=aparam
```

On the second (`nginx`), I should be able to do it the same way:

```
my.vhost.myOtherDomain.tld/apps?query=toto&params=aparam
```

Both applications include an `index.php` that is served correctly by both web servers.
However, the `/apps?` produce a 404 on `nginx`.

My guess is that `Apache` is doing some *magic* finding a `php` file to process the query.
However, I'm quite a noob with this tools and I don't understand what is exactly happening on the `Apache` server and how to configure `nginx` to reproduce the same behavior ...

Is `index.php` file processed as input?

So far I tried to specify `my.vhost.myOtherDomain.tld/index.php/apps?query=toto&params=aparam`
 with little success.
And to explore `Apache` configuration files without much help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To whoever might find this post through google:

Look at the hidden .htaccess, and rewrite its rules in nginx configuration.

Some websites can translate .htaccess style to nginx style configuration !

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using mod_rewrite in Apache, which changes how URLs are handled by the server.

You can try:

```
rewrite  ^apps$ apps.php last;
```

Check http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html

Comment: Ho god, the url rewriting... I totally forgot about this one !